# Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.menuOptions.map')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

Using Angular, React and ReactNG, I get this error:

`Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.menuOptions.map')`

Here is the code:

http://jsbin.com/xuranipuza/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are missing providing the attributes in your react directive element with respect to the `propTypes` that you are passing in. Because it then places a watch on these attribute values (reflecting the scope property name) and populate the props accordingly.

So:

```
 <sidebar-button menu-options="menuOptions" button-image="buttonImage" 
                button-image-mini="buttonImageMini" menu-option-bottom="menuOptionBottom">
 </sidebar-button>
```

**[Bin](http://jsbin.com/citipupawi/1/edit)**

Doc Says:

> The reactDirective service will read the React component propTypes and watch attributes with these names. If your react component doesn't have propTypes defined you can pass in an array of attribute names to watch. By default, attributes will be watched by value however you can also choose to watch by reference or collection by supplying the watch-depth attribute. Possible values are reference, collection and value (default).

Disclaimer: I have not used ng-react before.

Comment: Ah, OK, I thought if I put the array of values to watch it used them automatically. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Noah i debugged inside the ngReact and found out it iterates through the list and read the respective property values from attributes. You are welcome!!